# meteor deploy npm packages

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I use multiple npm packages in my meteor application, for instance the 'knox' package for amazon s3 access.

On my local system I don't have any problems, because I have the 'knox'- npm package installed on my system. But on the server this is obviously not the case.

I have read different suggestions what I could do:

1)

Install the npm module into the /public folder of my application
- unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

2)

I followed this tutorial:

[NPM Deploy Tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/srvdta)

I created packages/knox/package.js packages/knox/knox.js and I am pretty sure I did everything as described in the tutorial but this is not even working locally

Comment: What do you mean by "is not even working locally"? That's probably the lynchpin to getting it working remotely as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [npm](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm) package from Atmosphere. See [details](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm) on how to use it.

Comment: That doesn't do anything that you can't already do with a smart package and the `Npm.require` / `Npm.depends` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add the `knox` package to the `.meteor/packages` file?

The link you shared is pre Meteor 0.6.5, which loaded all packages in `packages/` automatically. Now, you need to specify them individually.